# Is php composer a break security compliance in linux production server?

Tags: php, linux, security, composer-php

I have used php composer for dependency management in PHP. It is really powerful.
But IT department in our company does not allow to run php composer on production environment because composer is required to run as root, so why? and what is my solution?

Thanks for every idea.

Comment: *"composer is require to run as root"* ~ nope, this is just plain wrong

Comment: thanks Phil, so that break security compliance?

Comment: Um, Composer does *not* require root to run. It can be run by any user as it provides PHP dependency management on a project level. Root would only be required if it needed to write to a place (it can write globally too) where it needed root permissions.